# How to prevent terminal from printing passwords from keychain?

Tags: security, keychain

I currently use the command-line utility `security` in a shell script to access a password from keychain. I am surprised that echoing my password variable works and reveals the password in my terminal window.

I used the function get_pw suggested [here](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20130722033452283) and then simply assign the password to a variable PASSWORD. Is it possible to make terminal hide the password?

My shell script looks as follows:

```
ACCOUNT_NAME='MyAccountName'

get_pw() {
   security 2>&1 >/dev/null find-generic-password -ga $ACCOUNT_NAME \
   | ruby -e 'print $1 if STDIN.gets =~ /^password: "(.*)"$/'
}

PASSWORD=$(get_pw)
```

Then when writing echo $PASSWORD, the password is revealed.

Comment: Please add some details. Do you run `PASSWORD=$(get_pw ...)` and see the password also in Terminal? If yes, please add your definition of `get_pw` to the question. If no, please add the commands you use.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I added it to the question.

Comment: See below, but I'm not sure what you expect to happen instead.

Answer (score 1):

Well,

```
PASSWORD=$(get_pw)
```

assigns the password to `PASSWORD` so it shouldn't be a surprise that

```
echo "$PASSWORD"
```

actually prints it on the Terminal.

The idea here is not to print it but to use it in another command to pass it on (as the example in the page you've linked to does). Even then the password is still visible in `ps -E` though.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Maybe I'm missing something but doesn't that mean that when I'd like keychain to reveal my password, it prompts for my admin pw. But if I try using security, it doesn't?

Comment: @PatrickBalada When I tried myself, I got prompted for my password to unlock the keychain. There is an "Allow always" option in the prompt, maybe you clicked this a while ago.

Comment: That's it. When I click it, terminal starts hiding the password. If you add this somehow to your answer, I'd love to accept it.

Comment: @PatrickBalada I'm not sure I understand what you are doing? Bash has no way of knowing that the string within `PASSWORD` is a password from Keychain, how does it turn hidden?